# Unit testing an Controller with AutoMapper issue

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to test a controller in my asp.netcore application. The test is failing because of auto-mapper.
I tried to mock to the auto-mapper but i do not know how to use it correctly.
Would anyone be able to suggest a way of overcoming this?
Thanks.

BooksController.cs

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public IActionResult GetBook(int id)
{
    var bookfromRepo = _repository.GetBook(id);
    var book = Mapper.Map<BookDto>(bookfromRepo);
    return Ok(book);
}
```

startup.cs

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Data.Database.Entities.Book, BookDto>();
});
```

ControllerTest.cs

```
[Fact(DisplayName = "GetBook")]
public void GetBook()
{
    //act
    var fakerepository = new Mock<IBPDRepository>();
    var sut = new BooksController(fakerepository.Object);

    //act
    var book = new BookDto();
    var viewModelBook = new BookDto {
        Id  =    1,
        Name = "C#", 
        Review = "good", 
        Pages = "500",
        Rating = "8",
        Price ="$10.00"
    };

    //var mockMapper = new Mock //stuck here;
    sut.GetBook(1);

    //assert
    IActionResult actionResult = sut.GetBook(2);
    Assert.Equal("C#",viewModelBook.Name);
}
```

Comment: What if your unit test initializes AutoMapper using the same call you have in startup.cs?

Comment: Yes that will work. Is that the best practice though?

Comment: You've mocked out the repository. The only thing left in your controller to test is the AutoMapper mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Mapper` to an `IMapper`, and then you can write something like that for the UnitTest :
(I'm doing that free-hand, so there might be slight adjustments to make)

```
[Fact(DisplayName = "GetBook")]
public void GetBook()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockBook1 = new Mock<BookDto>(Behavior = MockBehavior.Strict);
    var mockBook2 = new Mock<BookDto>(Behavior = MockBehavior.Strict);
    var mockRepository = new Mock<IBPDRepository>(Behavior = MockBehavior.Strict);
    mockRepository.Setup(r => r.GetBook(It.Is<int>(1)).Returns(mockBook1.Object)
    var mockMapper = new Mock<IAutoMapper>(Behavior = MockBehavior.Strict);
    mockMapper.Setup(m => m.Map<BookDto>(mockBook1.Object)).Returns(mockBook2.Object);

    // You might have to change the constructor.
    var sut = new BooksController(mockRepository.Object, mockMapper.Object);

    IActionResult actionResult;

    // Act
    actionResult = sut.GetBook(1);

    var actualBook = actionResult.Model as BookDto;

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(mockBook2.Object, actualBook);
}
```

The reason why I'd use mockBook rather than straight `BookDto` is that this way, combined with the *Strict* behavior, you know the method didn't change anything on it since you did no setup on it.